# Linter says redundant lambda, but when replaced as suggested it gives different error

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm reading [Real World Haskell - Chapter 10](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html).

All functions have common type `L.ByteString -> Maybe (a, L.ByteString)`
So then I looked into StateT definition which is `s -> m (a, s)` it exactly matches the above if it is written `StateT L.ByteString Maybe a`. So I decided to rewrite the first example using monad transformers. Hoping that

```
parseP5 :: StateT L.ByteString Maybe Greymap
parseP5 = do
   matchHeader (L8.pack "P5")
   skipSpace
   width <- getNat
   skipSpace
   height <- getNat
   skipSpace
   maxGrey <- getNat
   skipSpace
   _ <- getBytes 1
   bitmap <- getBytes (width*height)
   return (Greymap width height maxGrey bitmap)
```

would just work.

For example `matchHeader` function would become

```
matchHeader :: L.ByteString -> StateT L.ByteString Maybe ()
matchHeader prefix = \str ->
      if prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str
         then Just ((), str)
         else Nothing
```

But linter says that it has redundant lambda. But I have no idea how to write it without lambda. Can you help me with this one?

**UPDATE:**

When it is replaced like:

```
matchHeader prefix str=
      if prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str
         then Just ((), str)
         else Nothing
```

it gives another error

> Couldn't match expected type `L8.ByteString -> Maybe ((), L8.ByteString)`
> with actual type `StateT L8.ByteString Maybe ()`
> The equation(s) for matchHeader' have two arguments, but its type
> `L8.ByteString -> StateT L8.ByteString Maybe ()` has only one

Isn't `L8.ByteString -> Maybe((), L8.ByteString)` and `StateT L8.ByteString Maybe ()` same thing?

Comment: `f = \x -> ...` is the same as `f x = ...`. Does that help? The later is syntax sugar for the former, but the later is the preferred style.

Comment: replacing gives another error

Comment: Note that the replacement did *not* introduce the new error, your original code would have given the same one.  And correcting the compilation error isn't really possible without removing the opportunity for the suggested replacement at the same time.  I think normally hlint should only be run on code that already compiles without errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StateT s m a` is not a type alias for `s -> m (a, s)` but a `newtype` wrapper that is counted as a separate type by the type checker, so you have to wrap your lambda with the `StateT` constructor.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8

matchHeader :: L.ByteString -> StateT L.ByteString Maybe ()
matchHeader prefix = StateT $ \str ->
      if prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str
         then Just ((), str)
         else Nothing
```

You can also write the matcher without the lambda by using the `Monad` instance of `StateT`

```
matchHeader prefix = do
      str <- get
      if prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str
         then return ()
         else lift Nothing
```

This uses `get` to fetch the current state and then either returns `()` or "lifts" over the `StateT` transformer into the inner `Maybe` monad.

The above examples use the same logic as your original code, but you probably want to also strip the prefix from the state. You can also use `guard` from `MonadPlus` as Ørjan demonstrated to shorten the if-clause.

```
matchHeader :: L.ByteString -> StateT L.ByteString Maybe ()
matchHeader prefix = do
    str <- get
    guard (prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str)
    put $ L8.drop (L8.length prefix) str
```

Comment: is there a way to write it without lambda? if so can you show me?

Comment: I can't quite resist: ``matchHeader prefix = gets (prefix `L8.isPrefixOf`) >>= guard``

Comment: Yes, @DulguunLst, just use a `let` or `where` to define the function you pass to `StateT`.

Comment: `matchHeader prefix = do gets (L8.isPrefixOf prefix) >>= guard; gets (L8.drop (L8.length prefix)) >>= put` can this be shortened more?

Comment: @DulguunLst: You can use `modify (L8.drop (L8.length prefix))` instead of `gets`and `put` for the second statement.

Comment: wow thx, this way `skipSpace` becomes `modify (L8.dropWhile isSpace)`